# Can the Tilt of a Bezier curve "wrap around" from 360° to 0°?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a Bezier curve in the shape of a Möbius loop with a full twist of 360°. One of the end points has a Tilt value of 0, while the other has 360°. When I connect them, the curve twists between them.

[image: Connecting these two points gives an ugly twist]

Is there a way to connect them smoothly as if their tilt were equal? This should not be a problem mathematically as their normals are parallel to each other.

[image: This is what I would like to achieve]